# what is the most convenient way to build package for different environments?

Tags: java, maven, development-environment, production-environment

I have a maven project, which has quite different settings in the properties files for production and development envs. Is it right, that the most common way is to have different maven profiles (dev by default) which will package different properties during the build process?
Is there maybe another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what profiles are designed for.

You don't even need different properties files, you can have [one property file that gets filtered with different properties](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) from each `profile`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with profiles is that you need to run your build the number of times of your profiles. Which means if have five profiles (dev, pre-test, pre-live, qa, prod) you need to run your build five times. I would suggest to go a different way and produce as a result of a build direct those five artifacts (usually war's etc.) which have been configured appropriately. This can be achieved by using the [example](https://github.com/khmarbaise/multiple-artifacts) i have produced which makes life easiert. The example will produce

Comment: that is why you automate your builds with Jenkins

Comment: This will not change anything, cause the builds have to run multiple times..which is not needed...if you only need to run the whole build only once.

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach to put environment dependencies in an environment to have single artifact built from maven project and then provide properties during deployment. In this case maven doesn't know anything about particular environment.

E.g. you could put something `-Dmy.config.file=/path/to/env/my.properties` in java command line or by using JNDI, or reading properties from database, and so on.

This is more viable approach if you have a lot of different environments or you don't know anything about them (e.g. distributing a `.war` application to end-users).

Comment: no thanks, it's quite complicated to move all these properties DB or smth like that... it's easier to create another profile... although it's also has a problems